# web dependencies for play asset pipeline

Tags: playframework-2.0, asset-pipeline, webjars

I am coming from the Rails world and are now playing with play (2.1). I like that it comes with a kind of asset pipeline, but one thing I am missing is to include web-dependencies there. In Rails, I can add the `jquery-rails` dependency and include it in my application.js file to make it available.

I stumbled upon http://webjars.org which seems nice, but as far as I can tell I can only include the files directly in a html file.

Is there any way to enable this kind of behavior, or is it planed to be implemented in the near future?

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported in the same way as in Rails (apparently), so the best I've come up with is the following:

1. Include your WebJars dependencies
2. Define the WebJars route as [documented here](http://www.webjars.org/documentation)
3. Put your JavaScript file in `/app/assets/javascripts`
4. Use RequireJS (as [documented here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/RequireJS-support)) and the WebJars RequireJS loader to include the WebJars dependency

So, for example, let's say you want to use AngularJS.

Build.scala:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "webjars-play" % "2.1.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.0.7"
)
```

conf/routes

```
GET     /webjars/*file      controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

app/assets/javascripts/main.js

```
require(["webjars!angular.js"], function() {
  console.log(angular.isString(3));
}
```

app/views/example.scala.html

```
...
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js").url, module = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main").url)
...
```

Now the JavaScript console prints "false".